# Could loading a DLL into java result in increased CPU usage in java.exe?

Tags: java, dll, cpu

I have a java applet that loads a dll.   The dll is used to interface with a third party piece of software.   The dll launches the third party software and then is used to send data to and receive data from that software.    We occasionally are seeing a spike in CPU usage once the dll is loaded.   The spike is associated with java.exe not with the third party software.   But, the spike only occurs after the dll is loaded.     This is a lot of explanation for a very simple question.   Is it possible, that dll, itself could be consuming CPU and that this would show up on the system console as java.exe consuming a lot of CPU?

In other words, given a state where java.exe appears to be consuming a lot of CPU, could this be caused by a loaded dll?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: Try to use Process Explorer or so to see the stack trace of the hard-working thread in that java process. If the dll appears in the trace, most chances it's the offender (though it would not be a conclusive evidence, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when a dll is loaded, it is loaded 'into' a process. Any memory or CPU used by the dll is reported as part of the process that loaded it. If a dll function spikes the CPU when processing received data, it will be reported under the application that loaded the dll.

If you have [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), you can open the properties of a process. Right-click a process and choose properties, then go to the threads tab of the properties dialog. This can show the CPU usage per thread, and each thread is identified by the image (exe or dll) and its entry point.

Comment: ... However, you can't use the exe/dll listed for the thread to reliably tell whether the dll is causing your excess CPU usage.  You can get false negatives - the dll may cause usage on a thread listed for the exe.